# Using generic handler to implement proxy server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-handler

I have made a generic handler to implement the concept of proxy server in `asp.net` from the link below

[Source code link](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-create-simple-proxy-in-aspnet.html)

Now problem is i am opining a **google.com**, google page is opening but when i search something it gives me 404 error, I am running a website through visual studio.

I want when i open a google page it also allow me to search on that page, how can i remove 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Base HTML Tag for the URL you opened as below:

```
<base href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
```

I think your problem is that you open google.com, and the HTML `form` action is based on a relative path.

so when start search it try to do the action on your domain instead of google domain... which ends up with 404

if the base tag doesn't work i think you need to modify all the relative links inside the HTML before rendering it

Comment: where can i put base tag because i am giving the url in url bar not through code can you suggest me??

Comment: You need to inject it in inside the HTML that you read from the website